# How to get the correct DB2/400 library(database) using Squeryl Client

Tags: sql-server, database, squeryl, db2-400

I've installed Squeryl Client and can easily access my iSeries DB2/400 and select and see the data within the tables.  However, it seems I have to modify the URL in the alias every time I want to change from one library(database) to another. If I want to query a file(table) from library(database) "LibraryA", I use URL "jdbc:as400://www.system.com/LibraryA". If I want to query a file(table) from library(database) "LibraryB", I use URL "jdbc:as400://www.system.com/LibraryB". Even when I try to use a URL with a library list like "jdbc:as400://www.system.com/;libraries=LibraryA LibraryB", it only looks at the first library when trying to access a table in "LibraryB".

When I drag a table to the graph and select some fields, I would expect the sql to qualify the table with the library(database) name. After all, it knows which library the table is being dragged from. The generated sql looks like this:

SELECT
tableB.field1,tableB.field2
**FROM tableB**

What I would expect is for it to look something like this (iSeries sql syntax):

SELECT
tableB.field1,tableB.field2
**FROM LibraryB/tableB**

When I try to key over the generated SQL command, it still tries to access the table from
LibraryA.

If I use the URL ""jdbc:as400://www.system.com/", it will try to find a libary(database) named the same as my user ID.

When Squeryl Client can build the objects list showing the library and table I'm selecting, I should think it would be able to build a query to access the correct library as well.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have figured this out. I changed the URL to the following:
jdbc:as400://www.system.com/;**naming=system;** libraries=LibraryA LibraryB